# I need to capture a value from a URL and pass to another URL

Tags: javascript

I have the URL:

http://www.sampleurl.com/entrant-entry?entry=ca2f346b12cabcf2626b81c6900500ff

I need to take the value of `entry`, which in this case is `ca2f346b12cabcf2626b81c6900500ff` and attach it to the end of the destination URL:

http://ugc-4vets4life.market-online.net/voter-entry?entry=ca2f346b12cabcf2626b81c6900500ff

I have looked at several answers but none seem to make it clear to me.  I need to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
var url_string = "http://www.sampleurl.com/entrant-entry?entry=ca2f346b12cabcf2626b81c6900500ff";
var voter_url_string = "http://ugc-4vets4life.market-online.net/voter-entry?entry=";

var url = new URL(url_string);
var entry = url.searchParams.get("entry");

var final_url_string = voter_url_string + entry;
console.log(final_url_string);
```

Comment: Thanks @fuzz.  So when a user is on the page of the first URL with whatever the 'entry' value is in the address bar, I will give them a button to click to get to the destination URL which needs the 'entry' value dynamically attached to the end of the destination URL.

Comment: @TedLederer That's a separate question that you need to ask on StackOverflow. If this answer helped your initial question please accept it as an answer, create a new question and link to this answer.